# How can I set this pop up to only show/fire on the home page of the website?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins

I have a custom popup here https://odfigroup.com/ (made with php like a custom plugin)

It use to only fire when someone was on the home page and on only a certain number of visits but it does not seem to be working anymore.

So all I want it for this popup to display ONLY on the home page. And to fire every time someone hits these visit counts [1,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45]; //fire popup on page visit number

Here is my current code

```
<?php

function od_cookie(){ //sets cookies - bound to init
    if( !isset( $_COOKIE['odpop'] ) ){ // if cookie is not set set cookie to 1 ie first page load
        setcookie('odpop', 1, 0, '/');
    }else{
        $count = intval($_COOKIE['odpop']) + 1;
        setcookie('odpop', $count, 1, 0, '/'); // set cookie to session number
    }
    
}
add_action('init','od_cookie');


function odpopwp_fire(){
    
    $fireOn = [1,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45]; //fire popup on page visit number
    
    if(isset($_COOKIE['odpop'])){ //If cookie is set
    
        if(isset($_GET['odpop'])){ //if form has been submitted - GET REQUEST
            include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/odonnell-popup/public/templates/success-template.php'; 
            
        } elseif( in_array( $_COOKIE['odpop'], $fireOn ) == true ){//if cookie is equal to a value in $fireOn
            
            include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/odonnell-popup/public/templates/odpopwp-template.php';
        }
      
    }else{ //if cookie is not set set the cookie.
         include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/odonnell-popup/public/templates/odpopwp-template.php';
        
    }
    
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'odpopwp_fire');
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Surely you are missing a parameter in this line `setcookie('odpop', 1, '/');` check it against the other `setcookie()`

Comment: And this cookie will expire real quick `setcookie('odpop', $count, 1, '/');`

Comment: Check out [The PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) Someone spent days if not weeks writing it for this very reason

Comment: I will check thanks but I am not PHP guy. I didn't even make this popup. And those who did are no longer around for me to get assistance from. Hence reaching out here.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the home page to a static home page, you would use `is_front_page()`.

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
function odpopwp_fire(){
    
    $fireOn = [1,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45]; //fire popup on page visit number
    
    if(isset($_COOKIE['odpop'])){ //If cookie is set
    
        if(isset($_GET['odpop'])){ //if form has been submitted - GET REQUEST
            include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/odonnell-popup/public/templates/success-template.php'; 
            
        } elseif( in_array( $_COOKIE['odpop'], $fireOn ) == true ){//if cookie is equal to a value in $fireOn
            
            include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/odonnell-popup/public/templates/odpopwp-template.php';
        }
      
    }else{ //if cookie is not set set the cookie.
         include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/odonnell-popup/public/templates/odpopwp-template.php';
        
    }
    
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'odpopwp_fire');
}
```